# Get every product image url

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, reactjs, ruby

Im using **Rails** as my back-end and **React** as front-end.
Im already using `ActiveStorage` for File Uploads and had a successful upload throw front to back-end. The problem is that Im not able to send the `image url` with my json to my front-end to have an **image-preview** on page.
So I just want to send all image urls to front-end and show them up.

```
products_controller.rb

# Main Preview
  def index
    @product = Product.paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 3).order(created_at: :desc)
    @allProducts = Product.all
    @allProductsImage = Product.all.image
    @image = url_for(@allProductsImage)

    @allProductsImage.map { |product|
      product.as_json.merge({ image: url_for(product.image) })
    }
    
    render json: {
      products: @product,
      image_url: @image,
      allProducts: @allProducts,
      page: @product.current_page,
      pages: @product.total_pages
    }
  end



Product.jsx

const [imageSource, setImageSource] = useState("https://image.com/1920x1080");
useEffect(() => {
    AOS.init({});
    fetchProducts(currentApi);
    axios
      .get("/api/v1/products/index", { withCredentials: true })
      .then((response) => {
        setImageSource(response.data.image_url);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Check Login Error", error);
      });
  }, [imageSource]);
```

Every time I call **Product.image** I face *undefined method 'image'* and after using `Product.find(params[:id])`  I face to *cant find product by id error*.
I have seen some articles using serializer but I really dont want to use it.
How can I get image urls for each Product and render it as json in **`image_url`** part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Product
  def image_url
    Rails.application
         .routes
         .url_helpers
         .rails_blob_path(image)
  end
end
```

```
def index
  if params[:page].present?
    products = Product.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3)
    render json: {
      products: products.as_json(methods: :image_url),
      page: params[:page],
      per_page: 3 
    }
  else
    @products = Product.all
    render json: {
      products: products.as_json(methods: :image_url),
    }
  end
end
```

The way you have written the controller makes no sense at all. Including both the paginated and unpaginated records in the response defeats the entire purpose of pagination.

Having a single `image_url` key in the response also makes no sense. You're rendering a collection of images. What would that actually be? The image of the first product?

This will never work for that reason:

```
@allProductsImage = Product.all.image
```

`image` is an attribute of a single product and you're calling it on a whole collection of records.

Also be consisent with your naming. Either use *snake_case* or *camelCase* in your JSON responses - but never a mix.